# Errors trying to install PySpotify

Tags: python, pip, spotify

I'm trying to install the `PySpotify` plugin (https://github.com/mopidy/pyspotify) so that I can use the `libspotify Spotify` API to export playlists into `Spotify` from a webpage.

The directions in the documentation are:

1. Install `libspotify` using `homebrew` (done)
2. Install `pyspotify` using `pip`.

On step 2, I get a compilation error

```
src/artistbrowser.c:61: error: ‘SP_ARTISTBROWSE_FULL’ undeclared (first use in this function)

src/artistbrowser.c:61: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once

src/artistbrowser.c:61: error: for each function it appears in.)

src/artistbrowser.c:64: error: too many arguments to function ‘sp_artistbrowse_create’

lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//cc6Ui1hq.out (No such file or directory)

error: command 'llvm-gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

I don't know C, so I'm really not sure how to fix this manually. I tried editing the referenced file to add a declaration of `SP_ARTISTBROWSE_FULL`, but that just caused different compilation errors.

I suspect I probably just haven't installed something I need. Any ideas?

Comment: GCC 4.2? I'm using GCC 4.6.2. That version might be a little old.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the 1st step not being complete, is there some kind of sample thing you can compile to confirm that libspotify installed correctly?

Comment: I've done this before and it worked - do a `brew info libspotify` and make sure it's really recognized as installed.

Comment: birryree -- brew info libspotify seems to show that it's install and recognized...I'm trying updating GCC now to see if that helps

Comment: Solved eventually, in a stupid way. Probably not relevant to anyone else, but will leave this up just in case.

My problem was that there was something wrong with my homebrew installation, which was causing it to pull down an out of date versin of libspotify. That was making the pip installation of pyspotify fail. 

So, I wiped out my installation of homebrew, re-installed, re-installed libspotify, and then everything worked.

Comment: If you solved that question, please add that solution into answer section and mark it as accepted. It will help any other users who will be coming with same issue that you got in here.